# Close/cancel open X509Certificate2UI certificate selection and pin dialog programmatically without further user interaction

Tags: winforms, cryptography, x509

I have a function that is executed in a C# Task object (part of a Winforms .NET 4.7.2 application) that asks the user to select a certificate from the windows certificate store using the X509Certificate2UI class. 
There can be a situation where the corresponding selection dialog is open and waiting for user input when the task is canceled using the cancellation token. My expectation was that the selection dialog would then be automatically closed/canceled too, but it remains open.

The same problem applies to the dialog for entering the PIN securing the private key of a certificate.

Is there any clean way to cancel the dialog programmatically or to assure that it closes with the task?

The following code demonstrates the problem. One task opens the selection dialog. A second task simulates an event triggered after the dialog is opened. Once DoSomethingDifferent is done, the certificate is not required anymore and the selection dialog should therefore be closed. It however stays open until the program exits.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CancelCertificateDialog
{
class Program
{



    private static X509Certificate2 SelectCertificate()
    {
        // Selecte certificate from store
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2Collection selectedCertificate = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false);// (X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, true);

        selectedCertificate = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
        store.Certificates,
        "Certficates",
        "Select a certificate for signing the document",
        X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);


        return selectedCertificate[0];
    }


    private static void DoSomethingDifferent()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Console.WriteLine("I'm done");
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        Task<X509Certificate2> t1 = new Task<X509Certificate2>(() => SelectCertificate(), token);
        Task t2 = new Task(() => DoSomethingDifferent(), token);

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAny(t1, t2);
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < e.InnerExceptions.Count; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerExceptions[j]);
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("The certificate is not required anymore. Get rid of the dialog");
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Key");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please share a [MCVE].

Comment: Note that it depends a bit if the PIN dialog is generated by Windows or by smart card specific software. Do you know which one of the two? Is it a generic dialog as well or does it e.g. include a trademark or company name? @RezaAghaei That's a bit tricky, as including the Windows cert store is kind of hard. Still, your current code for generating / sending the cancellation token could be useful.

Comment: I have added a small C# program that demonstrates the problem. How can the task that opened the dialog be removed/stoped such that the dialog is also closed.